# Illinois resident, worked in New York and Boston, which state to file tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax

My home is in Illinois. I am in a New York college. I worked in college. I also worked a summer job in Boston. I received W-2 forms from my NY college and the Boston company. In which states should I file tax return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to read the rules in each state.  The answer may well be:  all of them.  You are least likely to have to file taxes in Illinois.

The general rule is that you file taxes in the states where you worked.  So if you worked in New York and Massachusetts, you almost certainly had taxes withheld there.  You'd file tax returns in each.

If you have any passive income, then you might be responsible for paying taxes on that in Illinois.  You could probably get away with filing that in New York, as that is where you usually reside.  Make sure that you declare all your income on at least one tax return.

But I can't say this enough:  read the rules in each state, even Illinois.  Don't rely on what we say; check for yourself.  Because the revenue agency won't accept our postings as an excuse.  You are responsible for paying your taxes properly.  This is especially true as you're talking about three different states potentially with three different rules.  Also, we don't know most of the specifics of your situation.  Something that you're not mentioning may turn out to be important.